# How to get the exit code for a failed BashOperator?

Tags: bash, airflow

I can integrate Slack notifications for failed processes based on [this helpful tutorial](https://medium.com/datareply/integrating-slack-alerts-in-airflow-c9dcd155105).

```
def task_fail_slack_alert(context):
    """
    Sends message to a slack channel.
    If you want to send it to a "user" -> use "@user",
        if "public channel" -> use "#channel",
        if "private channel" -> use "channel"
    """
    slack_channel = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).login
    slack_token = BaseHook.get_connection(SLACK_CONN_ID).password
    failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
        task_id='slack_failed',
        channel=slack_channel,
        token=slack_token,
        text="""
            :red_circle: Task Failed. 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url} 
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
        )
    )
    return failed_alert.execute(context=context)

task_with_failed_slack_alerts = BashOperator(
    task_id='fail_task',
    bash_command='exit 1',
    on_failure_callback=slack_failed_task,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

From the code example above, I can see that we can get information about the task using the `context` variable passed to the `task_fail_slack_alert(context)` function, e.g. `task=context.get('task_instance').task_id`

I'm wondering if we could make this slack notification more informative by including the actual reason for failure. If our bash script exits with particular exit codes, is this passed to the `context` dictionary which is sent to the `on_failure_callback` function?

For example:

```
if context.get('task_instance').error_code == 2:
    message_error = 'Duplicate Key Violation'
else:
    message_error = 'Unknown error, investigate logs'

failed_alert = SlackAPIPostOperator(
        task_id='slack_failed',
        channel=slack_channel,
        token=slack_token,
        text="""
            :red_circle: Task Failed. 
            *Task*: {task}  
            *Dag*: {dag} 
            *Execution Time*: {exec_date}  
            *Log Url*: {log_url}
            *Error*: {message_error} 
            """.format(
            task=context.get('task_instance').task_id,
            dag=context.get('task_instance').dag_id,
            ti=context.get('task_instance'),
            exec_date=context.get('execution_date'),
            log_url=context.get('task_instance').log_url,
            message_error=message_error,
        )
    )
return failed_alert.execute(context=context)
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [source code](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/_modules/airflow/operators/bash_operator.html) of the `BashOperator`:

```
:param xcom_push: If xcom_push is True, the last line written to stdout 
  will also be pushed to an XCom when the bash command completes.
:type xcom_push: bool
```

Edit: For more information on what `XCom` is and how you can use it, check out the documentation [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms)